# SQL How to pull in all records that don't contain

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a bit of a trick question to explain, but I'll try my best.

The essence of the question is that I have a employee salary table and the columns are like so,: Employee ID, Month of Salary, Salary (Currency).

I want to run a select that will show me all of the employees that don't have a record for X month.

I have attached an image to assist in the visualising of this, and here is an example of what UI would want from this data:

Let's say from this small example that I want to see all of the employees that weren't paid on the 1st October 2021. From looking I know that employee 3 was the only one paid and 1 and 2 were not paid. How would I be able to query this on a much larger range of data without knowing which month it could be that they weren't paid?

[image]

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using MS SQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your EmployeeSalary table against a list of expected EmployeeID/MonthOfSalary values, and determine the gaps - the instances where there is no matching record in the EmployeeSalary table. A LEFT OUTER JOIN can be used here, whenever there's no matching record / missing record in your EmployeeSalary table, the LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you NULL.

The following query shows how to perform the LEFT OUTER JOIN, however note that I've joined your table on itself to get the list of EmployeeID and MonthOfSalary values. You would be better to join these from other tables, i.e. I assume you have an Employee table with all the IDs in it, which would be more efficient (and more accurate) to use, than building the ID list from the EmployeeSalary table (like I've done).

```
SELECT EmployeeList.EmployeeID, MonthList.MonthOfSalary
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MonthOfSalary FROM EmployeeSalary) MonthList
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeSalary) EmployeeList
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeSalary 
  ON MonthList.MonthOfSalary = EmployeeSalary.MonthOfSalary
 AND EmployeeList.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID
WHERE EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to get the latest value, then to calculate the difference and make a filter on it. The filter can be done thanks to `having` clause.
I propose you the following starting point, that you might need to adapt, at least to cast some formats according to your column types.

```sql
with latest_pay as (
   -- Filter to get, for each employee, the latest paid month
   select Employee_ID, Month, Salary, max(month) as latest_pay_month
     from your_table
    group by Employee_ID
)
-- Look for employees not paid since more than 'your_treshold' months
select Employee_ID, latest_pay_month, Salary, datediff(latest_pay_month, getdate(), Month) as latest_paid_month_delay
   from latest_pay 
 having datediff(latest_pay_month, getdate(), Month) > your_threshold
```

Btw, I know it's an example, but avoid using column names such as `Month`, which would lead to confusions and errors with SQL keywords

Answer (score 0):

This is ideally where you would use a `calendar table` - having one available is handy for tasks such as this where you need to find missing dates.

You can build one on the fly, I have done so in this example however you would normally have a permanant table to use.

In order to determin which rows are missing you need to generate a list of expected rows, an `outer join` to your actual data will then reveal the missing rows.

So here we have a CTE that generates a list of dates (based on a date range you can set), followed by another to give a list of all the `EmployeeId` values.

You expect each employeeId to have a row for each month, so we do a `cross join` to generate the list of *expected* results, we then `outer join` with the actual data and filter to the `null` rows, these are the employees who have no been paid for that month.

[See example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccfce1311f9aff0a891b0aebde0c28a9)

```
declare @from date='20210101', @to date='20211001';

with dates as (
    select DateAdd(month,n,@from) dt from (
        select top(100) Row_Number() over(order by (select null))-1 n from master.dbo.spt_values 
    )v
), e as (select distinct employeeId from t)
select dt, e.EmployeeId
from dates d cross join e 
left join t on DatePart(month,d.dt)=DatePart(month,t.PaidDate) and t.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
where d.dt<=@to
and t.EmployeeId is null
```